# Layout View for iPhone6 Plus in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iphone-6

I can't able to get iPhone6 or iPhone6 Plus layout in Storyboard.
[image]

So how to add this? Because each time run on iPhone6 simulator and check, its tedious thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for dedicated iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus options as the iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 Plus dimensions are exactly the same. You should simply use one of those instead.

[image]

Comment: where is 1242x2208 resolution?

Comment: You should read [this article](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified) about iPhone resolution scaling. `1242x2208` is the rasterised resolution for iPhone 8 Plus. The points-based version of this is the left-most device highlighted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for little bit late in reply but I was not checked this so that.